# Combining Cycles and Eevee Renders Effects into one

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, eevee-render-engine

I am trying to make an animation scene of a Globe just like in the reference pic below (from Earth song): The main problem I am facing is with the clouds around the globe and the glow around the globe.

- **For Glow**: So what I was able to achieve till now was to use layer weight and use it as fac to mix the main image shader with an emission shader so that I can apply emission only around the globe and this works well in Eevee and the result is as shown in the below pic which I'm satisfied with!.
- **For Clouds**: I tried adding the **Volume scatter** to the clouds to get the effect as shown in the other picture which I rendered in Cycles. But, the same effect can not be obtained in Eevee as volume can be applied on only Box in Eevee. So I'm unable to get the same effect in Eevee.

**So, my question is, is there any way to use the two render engines to get the combined effect? Or is there any other way I can make the clouds look better??
and I prefer to use Eevee in this because Cycles would take a much longer time for the "animation".**

Btw, in Eevee I made the cloud material by using very basic Noise texture and using Transparent node. and the mesh of the clouds is, I took a sub-divided plane, deleted some faces and extruded (some double time) to get basic shape for the clouds and the used simple deform twice to make it into sphere and added Displace modifier (Voronoi). But the material looks really bad in Eevee, and better in Cycles.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Well, you can render the clouds separately using Cycles, and then use the *Compositor* to combine both animations. I'm no expert on that, though :).